# Are "elseif" and "else if" completely synonymous?

Tags: php, syntax, conditional-statements

Are `elseif` and `else if` completely synonymous, or is there a difference?

Does Zend have an accepted "standard" on which one to use?

While I personally dislike seeing `elseif` in the code, I just need to know if they're synonymous and the PHP manual isn't the easiest to search.

Comment: Not every other language uses `else if`, by the way. For instance, VB also uses `ElseIf` and Ruby uses `elsif`.

Comment: and shell/bash uses elif

Comment: python also uses elif

Comment: Note that the PSR-12 recommand to use `elseif` instead of `else if` [see documentation](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/)

Answer (score 248, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php):

> In PHP, you can also write 'else if' (in two words) and the behavior would be identical to the one of 'elseif' (in a single word). The syntactic meaning is slightly different (if you're familiar with C, this is the same behavior) but the bottom line is that both would result in exactly the same behavior.

Essentially, they will behave the same, but `else if` is technically equivalent to a nested structure like so:

```
if (first_condition)
{

}
else
{
  if (second_condition)
  {

  }
}
```

The manual also notes:

> Note that elseif and else if  will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets as in the above example. When using a colon to define your if/elseif conditions, you must not separate else if into two words, or PHP will fail with a parse error.

Which means that in the normal control structure form (ie. using braces):

```
if (first_condition)
{

}
elseif (second_condition)
{

}
```

either `elseif` or `else if` can be used. However, if you use the [alternate syntax](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), you must use `elseif`:

```
if (first_condition):
  // ...
elseif (second_condition):
  // ...
endif;
```

Comment: Good job with the example snippets. If anything, the alternate syntax is all that's necessary to prove that PHP simply treats `else if` as `else { if {`.

Comment: PHP doesn't treat `else if` as `else { if {`, otherwise you wouldn't able to do `if (0) { } else if (0) { } else { }`...

Comment: @GuidoHendriks: it's not that one is treated as the other, it's that they're functionally equivalent. Your example is equivalent to the nested form `if (0) { } else { if (0) { } else { } }`. Note there's no ambiguity in the last `else` block, which is always the case for complete branches (every `if` has an `else`).

Comment: Here's another example for reference http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php#115851

Comment: With alternate synyax you just have to remember 'colon' and endif of inner if:`if ($v1='1'):   
 do_thing();  
 else:  
  if($v1='b' ):  
    do_another_thing();  
   else:  
    do_smthing_else();   
   endif;  
 endif;` 
 
is the equivalent of;  

`if ($v1='1'):   
 do_thing();  
elseif($v1='b' ):  
 do_another_thing();  
else: 
 do_smthing_else(); 
endif;`

Answer (score 55):

The Framework Interoperability Group (FIG) which is made up of members that include the developers of Zend ( https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards#voting-members ) , put together a series of Standard recommendations (PSR-#).

Zend2 and Symfony2 already follows PSR-0.

There's no hard and fast rules for styles, but you can try and follow as much of PSR-2 as you can.

There's a comment on else if vs elseif in PSR-2:

> The keyword elseif SHOULD be used instead of else if so that all
>   control keywords look like single words.

https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#51-if-elseif-else

Some of the recommendations are just that, recommendations. It's up to you whether to use else if or elseif

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the keywords-as-one-word guideline.

Comment: So the recommondation implies that `else if` is a single control keyword that just happens to *look* like multiple words.

Comment: No, the coding guide style recommends using `elseif` to make all control words "single-words" over `else if`, which happens to behave exactly in the same way, but breaks the symmetry the author of the guide is looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, "elseif" and "else if" both are synonymous, alike in meaning and significance. You can mix "else if" with "elseif" together.

```
For Example - We can use "else if" and "elseif" together.
if($condition){
  ...
}
else if($condition){
  ...
}
elseif($condition){
  ...
}

Nested:
if($condition){
  ...
}
else if($condition){
  if($condition){
    ...
  }
  elseif($condition){
    ...
  }
}
```