# underlying difference between elseif vs else if

Tags: php

I was wondering the differnce between `elseif` and `else if`.

I was reading [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) which says if using the braces `{}` they are treated the same but only `elseif` works when not using the braces.

Also another contributer said:

> Note that } elseif() { is somewhat faster than } else if() {

and he backed it up with a benchmark test.

To me it seems like elseif is the true way of saying it and saying:

```
else if() {...}
```

is really the equivalent of:

```
else { if() {...} }
```

which might explain why its marginally slower.

I am used to using `else if` because thats how I do it in other languages as well. I don't really think it matters which way you type it (unless you are not using braces.. but I think its always good to use braces anyways) I was just curious about the underlying details.

Am I correct?

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662412/are-elseif-and-else-if-completely-synonymous Doesn't cover performance but may *suggest* that PHP treats `else if` as `else { if }`.

Comment: This question is certainly a dupe of my original one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are "elseif" and "else if" completely synonymous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662412/are-elseif-and-else-if-completely-synonymous)

Comment: This references speed of operation while the other didn't

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to my comment, from what I can see in the PHP source, the only speed boost is that PHP's parser has a special token for `elseif`, unsurprisingly known as `T_ELSEIF`. But I'm sure the speed boost is nothing more than a side effect of allowing `elseif` in the alternative syntax:

```
if (cond1):
    // Do something
elseif (cond2):
    // Do something else
else:
    // Do something else
endif;
```

Similar to Python, which uses `elif`, `else if` with a space wouldn't be allowed without having to unnecessarily complicate the parser's implementation code (i.e. to act differently between seeing a colon and the `if` keyword). So a colon is required directly after `else` and `if` respectively, and that's how the language rule is stipulated.

Ergo I'm pretty sure PHP just treats `else if` as a conditional block in a singular-statement `else`.

If there are any speed differences *at all*, blame the parser for most of them.

Comment: And, if i'm not wrong, PHP shouldn't care about spaces at all.

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli: Whitespace isn't an issue, it's the fact that Python and PHP's alternative syntax choke on seeing an `if` instead of a colon after `else`.

Answer (score 9):

In [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) I read out(See Note):

> Note: Note that elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the
>   same when using curly brackets as in the above example. When using a
>   colon to define your if/elseif conditions, you must not separate else
>   if into two words, or PHP will fail with a parse error.

Example:

```
<?php

/* Incorrect Method: */
if($a > $b):
    echo $a." is greater than ".$b;
else if($a == $b): // Will not compile.
    echo "The above line causes a parse error.";
endif;


/* Correct Method: */
if($a > $b):
    echo $a." is greater than ".$b;
elseif($a == $b): // Note the combination of the words.
    echo $a." equals ".$b;
else:
    echo $a." is neither greater than or equal to ".$b;
endif;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "speed difference" in that comment is not statistically significant. Aside from `else if:` not parsing, there's no effective difference.

Answer (score -3):

Regarding the efficiency, and based on what I have been studying for a long time. There is no difference.

Comment: Might as well share your results to confirm.

Comment: Thats wrong! Confirm your "study for a long time", but dont lie.