# If the operation is performed if the value in the list I'm looking for

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm the data with the following code.

```
$parametre = mysql_query("select * from faturaparametre where musteri='$musteri' and 
urungrubu='$urungrubu' and tasimasekli='$tasimasekli' and donem<= '$tarih' and donem2>= '$tarih' and teslimnoktasi='$teslimnoktasi1' and $agirlik BETWEEN min and max");
while($parametresonuc = mysql_fetch_array($parametre)) {


$fatparametreid = $parametresonuc[id];
$ynadresno = $parametresonuc[yuklemenokta];
```

Skip this procedure if you do not have the following variables: the next one in the list if there is no break in the last one in the search process, how can I do this?

```
    $adresil1 = mysql_query("select * from adresler where id='$yuklemenokta'");
$adressonuc1 = mysql_fetch_array($adresil1);


$yuklemeadresno = $adressonuc1[adresno];
$yuklemeil = $adressonuc1[noktail];
$yuklemeilce = $adressonuc1[noktailce];
$yuklemeilb = "il".$yuklemeil;
```

This code does not run more than one priority finding. and do not find exactly the same thing

```
if(eregi($ynadresno, "$yuklemeadresno")) {


$ftid = $fatparametreid;


}elseif(eregi($ynadresno, "$yuklemeilce")) {


$ftid = $fatparametreid;


}elseif(eregi($ynadresno, "$yuklemeilb")) {


$ftid = $fatparametreid;


}else {


}
```

Comment: Not the cause of your issue but array keys should be quoted: `$parametresonuc['id'];`.

Answer (score 0):

The array keys should be quoted,

```
$yuklemeadresno = $adressonuc1['adresno'];
$yuklemeil = $adressonuc1['noktail'];
$yuklemeilce = $adressonuc1['noktailce'];
$yuklemeilb = "il".$yuklemeil;
```

Comment: Nope. There's no (major) difference between `elseif` and `else if`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661508/

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks, never knew that :o

Comment: Just the quotes, I did not know `elseif` can be used. At @GünaySırbudak

Comment: @OptimusPrime: no worries :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the following code lists all. synchronize exactly what is included in the list needs to be.


    if(eregi("$ynadresno" , "$yuklemeadresno" )) {
    
    $ftid = $fatparametreid;
    echo"$ftid <br>";
    
    }else if(eregi("$ynadresno" , "$yuklemeilce")) {
    
    $ftid = $fatparametreid;
    echo"$ftid <br>";
    }else if(eregi("$ynadresno" ,  "$yuklemeilb")) {
    
    $ftid = $fatparametreid;
    echo"$ftid <br>";
    }else {
    
    }
    }

Comment: @GünaySırbudak No, i edited the answer, the elseif thing won't work, instead quote the keys in the arrays you have used.

Comment: Does exactly equating eregi? Does the character, even if in the past? I need a function to find exactly the same.

Comment: Sorry. I could not understand what are you asking. Array elements should be `$adressonuc1['adresno'];`, you have used `$adressonuc1[adresno];`

Comment: I'm with the following query data. results in the from "$ynadresno" area "10500001" in the process, which will have. If you do not pass to the next action.

Comment: $parametre = mysql_query("select * from faturaparametre where musteri='$musteri' and urungrubu='$urungrubu' and tasimasekli='$tasimasekli' and donem<= '$tarih' and donem2>= '$tarih' and teslimnoktasi='$teslimnoktasi4' and $agirlik BETWEEN min and max");
while($parametresonuc = mysql_fetch_array($parametre)) {
$fatparametreid = $parametresonuc['id'];
$ynadresno = $parametresonuc['yuklemenokta'];

Comment: if(eregi("$ynadresno" , "10500001" )) {

$ftid = $fatparametreid;
echo"$ftid <br>";

}else if(eregi("$ynadresno" , "772")) {
$ftid = $fatparametreid;
echo"$ftid <br>";
}else if(eregi("$ynadresno" ,  "il50")) {

$ftid = $fatparametreid;
echo"$ftid <br>";

}else {
}
}

Comment: Still don't get what you are asking, are you using a translator? Try `if(eregi($ynadresno , "10500001" ))`. No need to quote variables anywhere. Remove " " around variables.

Comment: if you are looking for in the list value($ynadresno) = ($ yuklemeadresno) If you have this line will assign the variable.
 ($ftid = $ fatparametreid;)

Comment: I am sorry, i am not able to understand what you are asking. Language problem.

Comment: If it is looking for ($yuklemeadresno) in the results($ynadresno) if the value to assign to the variable.