# Difference between else if and elseif

Tags: php, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [underlying difference between elseif vs else if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661508/underlying-difference-between-elseif-vs-else-if)

What is the difference between PHP conditions `else if` and `elseif` ...

`<?php`

`....`

`else if($count == 4) {}`

and

`elseif($count == 4) {}`

Is there any special case to use one or not? Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are “elseif” and “else if” completely synonymous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662412/are-elseif-and-else-if-completely-synonymous)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With curly braces, it makes no difference. When using a colon to define your conditions, 'else if' will fail due to parse error.

[See here for more details](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php).

Comment: else if equivalent   to `else { if() {...} }`

Comment: Don't downvote this guy, he's correct. Read the last note/example on the page he linked.

Comment: not from a performance standpoint. nesting your elseifs like that would be more taxing, but would also be less readable.

Answer (score 0):

Logically they are exactly the same.

They may be interpreted differently by the parser which may result in very slight performance differences.